# What are the predominant types of concrete pumps and what are their working mechanisms?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps

I've looked around for different types of [concrete pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_pump)s and simply don't know if there are many different types, what their mechanisms are and which ones are the most predominant ones.

What I've found:

- This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgmRN3BDE4E) explains how a pump with an S-shaped tube operates.
- The [relevant wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_pump) explains another type, which does differ in the way how the concrete is released

[image: An example of a concrete pump] (*a concrete pump*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found [a fairly comprehensive source](http://www.ritchiewiki.com/wiki/index.php/Concrete_Pump). There are five main types:

- **Mechanical pumps:** A piston and a rotary valve are used the push the concrete through.
- **Hydraulic pumps:** Hydraulics are used to pump the concrete.
- **Schwing pumps:** Two cylinders are used: One to receive concrete from the input hopper and one to release it into the output pipe. The two cylinders are connected by a flat gate valve. Apparently, Fredrich Schwing started [a company](http://schwing.com/about-us/) to manufacture concrete pumps. Unfortunately, their website does not have much information.
- **Thomsen pumps:** Similarly to the Schwing pump, two cylinders are used with internal pistons. The difference is that a flapper valve (a type of [check valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_valve)) is used.
- **Squeeze-crete pumps:** A rotating cylinder is used to squeeze the concrete through.